# PHP Regex preg_match_all div not same id

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, regex

I have a html page like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        ....
        <body>
            <div class="list-news fl pt10 ">
                Blue
            </div>
            <div class="list-news fl pt10 alternative">
                Yellow
            </div>
             <div class="list-news fl pt10 ">
                Red
            </div>
            <div class="list-news fl pt10 alternative">
                Cyan
            </div>
            <div class="list-news fl pt10 ">
                Black
            </div>
            <div class="list-news fl pt10 alternative">
                White
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Now i will write a sort php code for get all content i need

```
preg_match_all('@<div class="list-news fl pt10 .*?">(.*?)<div class="list-news fl pt10 .*?">@s',$rs,$match);
```

Now this is result

```
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => <div>Blue</div></div>
    [1] => <div>Red</div></div>
    [2] => <div>Black</div></div>
)
```

Result only show content in div `<div class="list-news fl pt10 ">` and not get content in `<div class="list-news fl pt10 alternative">` i can using str_replace for remove `alternative` class but if don't replace this string, how can get all content in every div match class `list-news fl pt10.*?`?

Thanks for idea.

Comment: use php DOM extension instead and search by xpath

Comment: Your regex, btw, isn't matching until the closing `</div`, but consumes the next opening; which is why it skips every other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) approach *(with a naive `contains`)*:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = <<<'EOD'
//div[
    contains(@class, 'list-news') and
    contains(@class, 'fl') and
    contains(@class, 'pt10')]
EOD;

$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

$results = array();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $results[] = trim($node->textContent);

}
print_r($results);
```

A regex approach *(with a naive pattern)*:

```
preg_match_all('~<div class="list-news fl pt10\b[^>]+>\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</div>)~',
               $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The two ways are a little naive because `contains` doesn't care about word boundaries and the classes order, and the regex pattern doesn't care about the possible irregularities of an html code.

The reason your pattern doesn't work is that you can't obtain overlapping matches. Since the first occurrence ends with `<div class="list-news...`, the next occurrence can't begin with the same `<div class="list-news...` that has been already matched.

Putting the last `<div class="list-news...` in a lookahead `(?=...)` *(that is only a check and where the content is not a part of the match result)* can be a way. However, it is more simple to use the closing tag `</div>`.

`\K` is used to remove all that has been matched before *(on the left)* from the match result.

A good compromise can be to extract all the div tags that contain a class attribute, and after to check with a regex if the attribute value is really what you want before extracting and triming the text content:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//div[@class]';

$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

$results = array();

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if ( preg_match('~(?:\s|^)list-news\s+fl\s+pt10(?:\s|$)~',
                    $node->getAttribute('class')) )
        $results = trim($node->textContent);
}
```

or without [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

$results = array();

foreach($divs as $node) {
    if ( $node->hasAttribute('class') &&
         preg_match('~(?:\s|^)list-news\s+fl\s+pt10(?:\s|$)~',
                    $node->getAttribute('class')) )
        $results = trim($node->textContent);
}
```